# MailMessage setting the Senders Name

Tags: c#

Is it possible to set the sender name on a `MailMessage` object? I tried setting it from `MailAddress`, but the `DisplayName` property seems to be read only.

I tried "My Name " as the sender and don't seem to work either.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("nerfDeathKnights@mycompany.com", "Bob Jones" );
```

Comment: +1 for noting that it takes a MailAddress object that can have both properties set.  With the other examples given, it assumes that the string is the e-mail address *and* display name.

Comment: I bump into an email address encoding problem, try the following code . MailAddress from = new MailAddress("jane@contoso.com",     "Jane " + (char)0xD8+ " Clayton", 
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: plus 1 for email address. minus 1 because it happened.

Comment: its not wokring for outlook office 365 email `MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("sender@xyz.com", "Sender Name");` this takes the user name automatically

Comment: @KumarV, is it possible somehow to set it for outlook office 365?

Answer (score 21):

You do not need to use the MailAddress class.

You can let the runtime parse your string.

```
var message = new MailMessage(
    "My Name my@name.com", 
    "Recipient One recipient@one.com,Recipient Two recipient@two.com",
    "Subject",
    "Body");
```

Answer (score -1):

From the MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
           "jane@contoso.com",
           "ben@contoso.com",
           "Quarterly data report.",
           "See the attached spreadsheet.");
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote because I'm not mean but this doesn't answer the OP's question... He wanted to know how to add a `DisplayName` to the `MailMessage`, not set the sender address

Comment: I'll downvote, because it doesn't answer the OP's question.  The citation is good, but answers are best done when the answer is in...well, your answer.