# Email from SSIS Script Task - Show sender name instead of address

Tags: c#, windows, ssis

I have developed a Script task for SSIS that sends an email from a Gmail account with the daily Sales numbers to some users. It works as expected but for a small little detail.

I want the email sender that appears in the inbox to be the sender name instead of the email address from which the email is sent).

The idea would be to get something like this:
[image: What I want]

Instead of what I get right now:
[image: What I get right now]

Any advice you can give to achieve this? I can't find any property to set up this "display name"...

Thank you all for your time!

Here is the main part of the code I am using:

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        try
        {            

            MailMessage MyMessage = new MailMessage();

            MyMessage.From = new MailAddress(Dts.Variables["$Project::SMTP_FROM_EMAIL"].Value.ToString());
            MyMessage.To.Add(Dts.Variables["$Project::SMTP_TO_DAILY_SALES_EMAIL"].Value.ToString());
            MyMessage.Subject = (Dts.Variables["User::EmailDailySalesSubject"].Value.ToString());
            MyMessage.Body = (Dts.Variables["User::DailySalesEmailBody"].Value.ToString());
            MyMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            MyMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

            var client = new SmtpClient(Dts.Variables["$Project::SMTP_SERVER"].Value.ToString(), Int32.Parse(Dts.Variables["$Project::SMTP_PORT"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Dts.Variables["$Project::SMTP_USERNAME"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["$Project::SMTP_PASSWORD"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString()),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            client.Send(MyMessage);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        } ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MailMessage setting the Senders Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231917/mailmessage-setting-the-senders-name)

Comment: SOLVED. I finally realized what I was missing (the second part of the .From property): `MyMessage.From = new MailAddress(Dts.Variables["$Project::SMTP_FROM_EMAIL"].Value.ToString(), "SENDER NAME");`

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I finally realized what I was missing (the second part of the .From property):

```
MyMessage.From = new MailAddress(Dts.Variables["$Project::SMTP_FROM_EMAIL"].Value.ToString(), "SENDER NAME");
```

Comment: Since this is the same as the duplicate, the usual protocol at StackOverflow is to close the question (as duplicate) rather than post an answer here.